# Python - Adding two specific values if another set of values are the same

Tags: python, list

I'm in the middle of writing a python program and I have to add two ints (the players points) together if the "teams" are the same. There are two players per team.

My list looks something like this:

```
list = [["team1", 10],["team2", 20],["team1", 30],["team3",0],["team2",5]]
```

How do I add the values from `team1` together and then `team2` and so?

I want the final list (doesn't matter if it's a seperate list) to look like this:

```
list2 = [["team1", 40],["team2", 25],["team3",0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) or a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
list1 = [["team1", 10],["team2", 20],["team1", 30],["team3",0],["team2",5]]

from collections import Counter, defaultdict

counter = Counter()  # alternatively: counter = defaultdict(int)
for team, score in list1:
    counter[team] += score
list2 = list(counter.items())

print(list2)
# output: [('team2', 25), ('team1', 40), ('team3', 0)]
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thanks!